# Removing php extension from XML sitemap generator

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sitemap

My developer is out for holidays and I'm trying to figure out how to remove php extension from my XML sitemap generator.

Here's the code that's needs to be changed:

```
    //remaining main pages:
$pages=array();
$query="SELECT DISTINCT strona FROM `sites_table`";
if($result=$GLOBALS['mysql']->query($query))
{
    $i=0;
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($row['site']!="/index.php")
        {
            $pageName=substr($row['site'],1);
            array_push($pages,$pageName);
            write(insertIntoTemplate($pageName,"0.8","hourly"));
        }
    }
    $result->free();
}
else 
    echo $dbErrorMsg;
```

The MySQL query just prints the array of sites like: news.php, sports.php, politics.php etc.

All I need is just remove this .php extension ;) I've did that already with special .htaccess file but now I need to just inform Google that I'm using non .php sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that $pageName was also uses for some other pages, so I just did it this way and no errors now:

```
            //do a string replace of all occurrences of .php 
            $pageName=substr($row['site'],1);
            array_push($pages,$pageName);
            $pageName2=substr(str_replace('.php','',$row['site']),1);
            array_push($pages,$pageName);
            write(insertIntoTemplate($pageName2,"0.8","hourly"));
```

Comment: Did you talk to your developer? You do realize you may be adding urls which don't exist? If your sitemap is full of 404s you will get errors raised in Google's Webmaster Tools control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be able to change the line:

```
$pageName=substr($row['site'],1);
```

to:

```
$pageName=substr($row['site'],1, -4);
```

Note:  All this code does is remove the last four characters - this may break other sections of the site if there are places where the extension is expected, items that don't follow the .php model, etc.

Comment: Almost close, but my sitemap is now all `<loc>http://domain.com/</loc>` and that's it. I need `http://domain.com/sports` etc. Also got such warning: `Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/admin/domain.com/sitemap.php on line 189`

Comment: There should be somewhere something like this I think: `$temp=str_replace(".php","",$page);`

Comment: Without seeing the actual data, I can't really do much . . . the code I provided assumes that $row['site'] is full of things like '/index.php', '/sports.php', etc.  It looks like my caveat is coming true as well, in that it's expecting the .php elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, so long as you are ok with replacing all occurrences of .php with an empty string.  This does not take into account any edge cases that may exist in your application, and you'd need to speak with your developer to know this for sure if you are unsure yourself.

```
//remaining main pages:
$pages=array();
$query="SELECT DISTINCT strona FROM `sites_table`";
if($result=$GLOBALS['mysql']->query($query))
{
    $i=0;
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($row['site']!="/index.php")
        {
            //do a string replace of all occurrences of .php 
            $pageName=substr(str_replace('.php','',$row['site']),1);
            array_push($pages,$pageName);
            write(insertIntoTemplate($pageName,"0.8","hourly"));
        }
    }
    $result->free();
}
else 
    echo $dbErrorMsg;
```

Comment: It works :) It popped a lot of warnings like this: Warning: file_get_contents(index): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/admin/domain.com/sitemap.php on line 190, but map is generated properly :)